# Is that possible to use Camera in Photo Editing Extension in iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios8, ios-extensions

I am trying to create a simple Photo editing extension.I want to use custom camera with filters as a extension, but Apple document suggest that photo editing extension use assets from photo library.Is this a limitation of the extension? If not, can you please guide me how to accomplish this? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't get exact question but [HERE][1] you will some clue about extension.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917538/ios8-extension-share-images-between-container-and-extension?rq=1