# Access main app bundle from within an extension (Mac / iOS)

Tags: xcode, ios-app-extension, appstore-sandbox

I would like to access the main app resource folder, in order to share assets rather than duplicating them and increasing the app package size.

By default, there are no permission to access the resource folder of the main too from the extension process.

It's possible to copy them from the main app to a [group container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917538/ios8-extension-share-images-between-container-and-extension), but
if the extension runs before the main app, it will not work.

Is it possible to add permissions to the extension process to access the main app's bundle files?