# What is the best way to share user generated images between host app and today extension

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I know that to share data between main app and widget is to use NSUserDefaults or CoreData, but both of them are not recommended way to share images. To store **user generated images**, app should use app's Documents directory but it isn't accessible from widget, then how should the app share the images with it's widget?

Comment: try to check with App groups feature.

Comment: @karthikeyan, that works but it isn't recommended way to store images, so what is the correct method?

Comment: anyway you need to convert image to data, if you are using db.same thing here convert it and use app groups. why its not recommended way?

Comment: yes, that's what I did, converted image to data to store, I just want to let user set the widget background image so I'm not using db. Should I go with the same approach?

Comment: did you get it image data in widget? if you are plan to multiple image, don't follow this way some one faced problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917538/ios8-extension-share-images-between-container-and-extension

Comment: if its just a background image, then its ok. http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions

Comment: thanks for the links, I dint know about creating directory in app groups. However if image is too big, even my app widget not loading, I guess using shared documents directory will fix it.

Comment: yes i think so, let me know once you fix.They given example projects also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used shared app group directory to save the image and access it from both container app as well as extension, here's the code.

Save image

```
 public func saveImage(image:UIImage){        
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let directory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "yourappgroup")?.appendingPathComponent("yourImagename.jpg")
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: (directory?.path)!, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
}
```

Get saved image

```
public func saveImage() -> UIImage {
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    if let imagePath = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "yourappgroup")?.appendingPathComponent("yourImagename.jpg").path {            
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath){                
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
        }else{
            print("No Image")                
            return nil
        }
    }
```